# Format decimal to two places or a whole number

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

For 10 I want 10 and not 10.00
For 10.11 I want 10.11

Is this possible without code?  i.e. by specifying a format string alone simlar to 
{0:N2}

Comment: @RyanGates, duplicate of a newer question? :P

Comment: My suggestion is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33180829/2321042

Comment: @Andrew An older question can be a duplicate of a newer question provided that there are better answers. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/299327

Comment: @RyanGates, thanks for that! When flagging, it just says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer". I agree the other thread is more complete than this one. :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
decimal num = 10.11M;

Console.WriteLine( num.ToString( "0.##" ) );
```

Comment: This doesn't work - 

decimal num = 10.1;

The best I can come up with is: num .ToString("C").Replace(".00", "");

Anyone who has the answer for this case would be helping me!

Comment: @Dave - what doesn't work?  Is it that you want exactly 2 decimals unless they are zero?

Comment: @Dave - How about `num % 1 == 0 ? num.ToString("0") : num.ToString("0.00");`  You could implement it as an extension method on decimal.

Comment: Console.WriteLine( num.ToString( "0.00" ) ); forces 2 DP even if the value is zero. i..e "0.00" or "0.10" etc. Don't forget default behavior is to round up from .005 not down.

Comment: @dotNETNinja that's what Dave was asking for. In retrospect I might do  `decimal.Truncate(num) == num` instead of mod by 1, though.

Comment: this worked for me under mono... if you really have to use string operations to get this right, don't forget string.trimRight(new char[]{'0'}) to trim any trailing zeros - but do check that there is a decimal separator first

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the decimal precision is intrinsic to the decimal type, which defaults to 4 decimal places. If I use the following code:

```
decimal value = 8.3475M;
Console.WriteLine(value);
decimal newValue = decimal.Round(value, 2);
Console.WriteLine(newValue);
```

The output is:

```
8.3475
8.35
```

Comment: I think this doesn't answer what Neil asked.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using CultureInfo. Use the below using statement to import the library.

```
using System.Globalization;
```

For the decimal conversion, ## can be used for optional decimal places and 00 can be used for mandetory decimal places. Check the below examples

```
double d1 = 12.12;
Console.WriteLine("Double :" + d1.ToString("#,##0.##", new CultureInfo("en-US")));

String str= "12.09";
Console.WriteLine("String :" + Convert.ToDouble(str).ToString("#,##0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US")));

String str2 = "12.10";
Console.WriteLine("String2 with ## :" + Convert.ToDouble(str2).ToString("#,##0.##", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
Console.WriteLine("String2 with 00 :" + Convert.ToDouble(str2).ToString("#,##0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US")));


int integ = 2;
Console.WriteLine("Integer :" + Convert.ToDouble(integ).ToString("#,##0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

the results are as follows

```
Double :12.12
String :12.09
String2 with ## :12.1
String2 with 00 :12.10
Integer :2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the number to a `decimal`, then use its `ToString` with formatting `"#,##0.##"`.

The format means "for values > 3 digits, use thousand separators. Always show a digit before the decimal separator. Optionally show up to 2dp."

```
decimal a = 5000000;
decimal b = 5000;
decimal c = 5;
decimal d = 2.5m;
decimal e = 0.0005m;
decimal f = 0.45m;
decimal g = 0.499m;
decimal h = 0.51515m;
decimal i = 123456.789m;
decimal j = 10.1m;

// Answers in my English localization       
string format = "#,##0.##";
Console.WriteLine("a=" + a.ToString(format)); // 5,000,000
Console.WriteLine("b=" + b.ToString(format)); // 5,000
Console.WriteLine("c=" + c.ToString(format)); // 5
Console.WriteLine("d=" + d.ToString(format)); // 2.5
Console.WriteLine("e=" + e.ToString(format)); // 0
Console.WriteLine("f=" + f.ToString(format)); // 0.45
Console.WriteLine("g=" + g.ToString(format)); // 0.5
Console.WriteLine("h=" + h.ToString(format)); // 0.52
Console.WriteLine("i=" + i.ToString(format)); // 123,456.79
Console.WriteLine("j=" + j.ToString(format)); // 10.1
```

If you *require* 2dp, use `"#,##0.00"` instead, but this will always show .00 for a whole number.