# Using String Format to show decimal up to 2 places or simple integer

Tags: c#, regex, string-formatting, number-formatting

I have got a price field to display which sometimes can be either 100 or 100.99 or 100.9, What I want is to display the price in 2 decimal places only if the decimals are entered for that price , for instance if its 100 so it should only show 100 not 100.00 and if the price is 100.2 it should display 100.20 similarly for 100.22 should be same .
I googled and came across some examples but they didn't match exactly what i wanted :

```
// just two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net Format decimal to two places or a whole number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148271/net-format-decimal-to-two-places-or-a-whole-number)

Comment: RE: "What I want is to display the price in 2 decimal places only if the decimals are entered for that price" -- so if the user types "100.00" you want to show "100.00", but if they type "100" you only want to show "100"? -- number types only track the value of the number -- not which of the insignificant digits were entered by a user and which were not -- for that you will need to use a string.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I think that this question may be a duplicate, but it has much better and more complete answers. IMO the other one should be marked as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: just add   .Replace(".00","")

Comment: All you need is `value`.ToString("0.##");

Comment: @Mehdi - Your suggestion would not work for `100.2`. He wants to get `"100.20"`, not `"100.2"`.

Comment: mmm, you're right! I should've read the Q more carefully.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

An inelegant way would be:

```
var my = DoFormat(123.0);
```

With `DoFormat` being something like:

```
public static string DoFormat( double myNumber )
{
    var s = string.Format("{0:0.00}", myNumber);

    if ( s.EndsWith("00") )
    {
        return ((int)myNumber).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Not elegant but working for me in similar situations in some projects.

Comment: This isn't really the question that was asked -- but had it been -- why not just use string.Format("{0:0.00}").Replace(".00", "")?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: depending on the current thread's `CurrentCulture`, decimal separator might not be `.`. Unless `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is used with `string.Format`, you would have to check the value of `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`, and that would be a real PITA. :)

Comment: @Uwe Keim What if i have `60000` int and I want it to be `60.000`?

Comment: This answer is a case of "reinventing a square wheel".  Does not take into account culture or the fact that this has already been handled by .NET.

Answer (score 699):

Sorry for reactivating this question, but I didn't find the right answer here.

In formatting numbers you can use `0` as a mandatory place and `#` as an optional place.

**So:**

```
// just two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);         // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
```

You can also combine `0` with `#`.

```
String.Format("{0:0.0#}", 123.4567)       // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.0#}", 123.4)          // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.0#}", 123.0)          // "123.0"
```

For this formating method is always used `CurrentCulture`. For some Cultures `.` will be changed to `,`.

### Answer to original question:

The simpliest solution comes from @Andrew ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335#33180829)). So I personally would use something like this:

```
var number = 123.46;
number.ToString(number % 1 == 0 ? "0" : "0.00");
```

Comment: At first, I thought this should be the answer, until I re-read the original question multiple times. The OP is not entirely clear what he exactly wants, but it seems he always wants 2 decimal places if someone enters a fraction. So if someone entered 1.1 then he'd want 1.10; this code wouldn't do that.

Comment: Oops, I read it again and you're right.
So, this isn't the right answer but at least someone might find this useful.

Comment: What OP needed can be achieved with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33180829/2321042

Comment: I just found it useful, and (somewhat) matching what a BoundField in a GridView does with a SqlDouble and no format instruction. You have to indicate the max# you'll show. (Vs. BoundField, happy to show as many or as few as you like)

Answer (score 95):

This is a common formatting floating number use case.

Unfortunately, all of the built-in one-letter format strings (eg. F, G, N) won't achieve this directly.
For example, `num.ToString("F2")` will always show 2 decimal places like `123.40`.

You'll have to use **`0.##`** pattern even it looks a little verbose.

A complete code example:

```
double a = 123.4567;
double b = 123.40;
double c = 123.00;

string sa = a.ToString("0.##"); // 123.46
string sb = b.ToString("0.##"); // 123.4
string sc = c.ToString("0.##"); // 123
```

Comment: But he wants 123.40, not 123.4.

Comment: Not solving this question but solving mine. I upvote this to come up for everyone else to see.

Answer (score 67):

Old question but I wanted to add the simplest option in my opinion.

**Without** thousands separators:

```
value.ToString(value % 1 == 0 ? "F0" : "F2")
```

**With** thousands separators:

```
value.ToString(value % 1 == 0 ? "N0" : "N2")
```

The same but with **String.Format**:

```
String.Format(value % 1 == 0 ? "{0:F0}" : "{0:F2}", value) // Without thousands separators
String.Format(value % 1 == 0 ? "{0:N0}" : "{0:N2}", value) // With thousands separators
```

If you need it in **many places**, I would use this logic in an **extension method**:

```
public static string ToCoolString(this decimal value)
{
    return value.ToString(value % 1 == 0 ? "N0" : "N2"); // Or F0/F2 ;)
}
```

Answer (score 31):

try

```
double myPrice = 123.0;

String.Format(((Math.Round(myPrice) == myPrice) ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}"), myPrice);
```

Comment: string.Format((number % 1) == 0 ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}", number);

Answer (score 15):

If your program needs to run quickly, call value.ToString(formatString) for ~35% faster string formatting performance relative to $"{value:formatString}" and string.Format(formatString, value).

### Data

[image: C# String Formatting Performance - VS2017 15.4.5]

### Code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class StringFormattingPerformance
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("C# String Formatting Performance");
      Console.WriteLine("Milliseconds Per 1 Million Iterations - Best Of 5");
      long stringInterpolationBestOf5 = Measure1MillionIterationsBestOf5(
          (double randomDouble) =>
          {
             return $"{randomDouble:0.##}";
          });
      long stringDotFormatBestOf5 = Measure1MillionIterationsBestOf5(
          (double randomDouble) =>
          {
             return string.Format("{0:0.##}", randomDouble);
          });
      long valueDotToStringBestOf5 = Measure1MillionIterationsBestOf5(
          (double randomDouble) =>
          {
             return randomDouble.ToString("0.##");
          });
      Console.WriteLine(
$@"            $""{{value:formatString}}"": {stringInterpolationBestOf5} ms
 string.Format(formatString, value): {stringDotFormatBestOf5} ms
       value.ToString(formatString): {valueDotToStringBestOf5} ms");
   }

   private static long Measure1MillionIterationsBestOf5(
       Func<double, string> formatDoubleUpToTwoDecimalPlaces)
   {
      long elapsedMillisecondsBestOf5 = long.MaxValue;
      for (int perfRunIndex = 0; perfRunIndex < 5; ++perfRunIndex)
      {
         var random = new Random();
         var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
         for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
         {
            double randomDouble = random.NextDouble();
            formatDoubleUpToTwoDecimalPlaces(randomDouble);
         }
         stopwatch.Stop();
         elapsedMillisecondsBestOf5 = Math.Min(
            elapsedMillisecondsBestOf5, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
      }
      return elapsedMillisecondsBestOf5;
   }
}
```

### Code Output

```
C# String Formatting Performance
Milliseconds Per 1 Million Iterations - Best Of 5
            $"{value:formatString}": 419 ms
 string.Format(formatString, value): 419 ms
       value.ToString(formatString): 264 ms
```

### References

[Custom Numeric Format Strings [learn.microsoft.com]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

[Qt Charts BarChart Example [doc.qt.io]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-barchart-example.html)

Comment: Great to know it can be done within the $string notation. And if it's not used in a tight loop, then no worries about the performance hit.

Comment: This is mainly due to boxing and other extra allocations. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63904747/419761) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of anyway to put a condition in the format specifier, but you can write your own formatter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
               // all of these don't work
            Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", 10);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:00.0}", 10);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:0}", 10);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", 10);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:0}", 10.0);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:0}", 10.1);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", 10.1);

          // works
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new MyFormatter(),"{0:custom}", 9));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new MyFormatter(),"{0:custom}", 9.1));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class MyFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {
        public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            switch (format.ToUpper())
            {
                case "CUSTOM":
                    if (arg is short || arg is int || arg is long)
                        return arg.ToString();
                    if (arg is Single || arg is Double)
                        return String.Format("{0:0.00}",arg);
                    break;
                // Handle other
                default:
                    try
                    {
                        return HandleOtherFormats(format, arg);
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        throw new FormatException(String.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid.", format), e);
                    }
            }
            return arg.ToString(); // only as a last resort
        }

        private string HandleOtherFormats(string format, object arg)
        {
            if (arg is IFormattable)
                return ((IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            if (arg != null)
                return arg.ToString();
            return String.Empty;
        }

        public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
        {
            if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
                return this;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative to Uwe Keim's method, which would still maintain the same method call:

```
var example1 = MyCustomFormat(123.1);  // Output: 123.10
var example2 = MyCustomFormat(123.95); // Output: 123.95
var example3 = MyCustomFormat(123);    // Output: 123
```

With `MyCustomFormat` being something like:

```
public static string MyCustomFormat( double myNumber )
{
    var str (string.Format("{0:0.00}", myNumber))
    return (str.EndsWith(".00") ? str.Substring(0, strLastIndexOf(".00")) : str;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me as it seems TrimEnd takes an array of chars like {',', '.', ' '} rather than a string like ".00" - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx

Comment: You're right - not sure how I missed that. I've updated to work correctly.

Comment: Depending on the current thread's `CurrentCulture`, decimal separator might not be `.`. Unless `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is used with `string.Format`, you would have to check the value of `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`, which is rather inelegant.

Answer (score 7):

Simple one line code :

```
public static string DoFormat(double myNumber)
{
    return string.Format("{0:0.00}", myNumber).Replace(".00","");
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is if it is run where the decimal separator is a comma. Check the comments for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951366/2321042).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var number = 123.4567;
var str = number.ToString("N2");
```

Comment: Thanks for your recomandation @help-info.de , that's right :)

Comment: For me, this displays the value 100 as 100.00, which is not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid there is no built-in format that will do this. You will have to use a different format depending on whether the value is a whole number or not. Or always format to 2 decimal places, and manipulate the string afterwards to remove any trailing ".00".

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(totalPrice));
```

Comment: This will fail on a culture where point is used as a thousands separator. I just tried it now.

Answer (score 4):

If none of the other answers work for you, it may be because you are binding the `ContentProperty` of a control in the `OnLoad` function, which means this won't work:

```
private void UserControl_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Bind.SetBindingElement(labelName, String.Format("{0:0.00}", PropertyName), Label.ContentProperty) 
}
```

The solution is simple: there is a `ContentStringFormat` property in the xaml. So when you create the label do this:

```
//if you want the decimal places definite
<Label Content="0" Name="labelName" ContentStringFormat="0.00"/>
```

Or

```
//if you want the decimal places to be optional
<Label Content="0" Name="labelName" ContentStringFormat="0.##"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

something like this will work too:

```
String.Format("{0:P}", decimal.Parse(Resellers.Fee)).Replace(".00", "")
```

Comment: That gives a percent?

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with decimals coming from a (T-)SQL database, you want to be able to convert nullable and non-nullable decimals with x decimal places and be able to review the code easily against your table definitions - and of course, display the right number of decimals to the user.

Unfortunately, the Entity Framework doesn't automatically convert something like a SQL `decimal(18,2)` into a .NET equivalent with the same number of decimal places (since there is only decimal with full precision available). You have to truncate the decimal places manually.

So, I did it this way:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToStringDecimal(this decimal d, byte decimals)
    {
        var fmt = (decimals>0) ? "0." + new string('0', decimals) : "0";
        return d.ToString(fmt);
    }

    public static string ToStringDecimal(this decimal? d, byte decimals)
    {
        if (!d.HasValue) return "";
        return ToStringDecimal(d.Value, decimals);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
void Main()
{
    decimal d = (decimal)1.2345;
    decimal? d2 = null; 

    Console.WriteLine(d.ToStringDecinal(2)); // prints: "1.23" (2 decimal places)
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToStringDecinal(0)); // prints: "1" (show integer number)
    Console.WriteLine(d2.ToStringDecimal(2)); // prints: "" (show null as empty string)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the code more clear that Kahia wrote in (it is clear but gets tricky when you want to add more text to it)...try this simple solution.

```
if (Math.Round((decimal)user.CurrentPoints) == user.CurrentPoints)
     ViewBag.MyCurrentPoints = String.Format("Your current Points: {0:0}",user.CurrentPoints);
else
     ViewBag.MyCurrentPoints = String.Format("Your current Points: {0:0.0}",user.CurrentPoints);
```

I had to add the extra cast (decimal) to have Math.Round compare the two decimal variables.

Answer (score 1):

A recent project has a similar requirement. I wrote this decimal extension method,
which uses the [currency ("C") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier). In addition to removing zeros, it also has options for decimal digits precision, currency symbol, separator and culture.

```
public static DecimalExtension{

     public static string ToCurrency(this decimal val, 
                                     int precision = 2, 
                                     bool currencySymbol = false, 
                                     bool separator = false, 
                                     CultureInfo culture = null)
      {     
         if(culture == null) culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                                                   
         NumberFormatInfo nfi = culture.NumberFormat;
         nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = precision;
            
         string zeros = new String('0', precision);       
                    
         //Remove zeros
         var result = val.ToString("C",fi).Replace(nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator + zeros,"");
                     
         if(!separator) result = result.Replace(nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator,"");
                    
         return currencySymbol? result: result.Replace(nfi.CurrencySymbol,"");      
        }   
}
```

Examples:

```
decimal Total = 123.00M;
Console.WriteLine(Total.ToCurrency());  
//output: 123

decimal Total = 1123.12M;
Console.WriteLine(Total.ToCurrency()); 
//Output:  1123.12

Console.WriteLine(Total.ToCurrency(4));
//Output:  1123.1200

Console.WriteLine(Total.ToCurrency(2,true,true));
//output:  $1,123.12
 
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR")  //Brazil
Console.WriteLine(Total.ToCurrency(2,true,true, culture));
//output:  R$ 1.123,12
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
string Output = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Decimal.Parse(InputStringValue));
```