# Show extra decimal place as Double in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I tried to display the temperature.  I set the temperature to be a double, when I get a temperature, e.g. 77 F, I really want to display 77.0 but I do not know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a double to two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418668/formatting-a-double-to-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the format specifier F

```
Dim Temperature As Double
Temperature = 77
Console.WriteLine(Temperature.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Will display 77.0

[See Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

```
Dim value As Double
value = 70
Console.Writeline(value.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

displays: 70.0

Make sure you search for an answer before posting a question (e.g. "vb.net number format"). I'm surprised the site did not offer you related questions/ answers when you were typing up the question.