# is it possible to assign two decimal places to a double

Tags: c#

I have looked online and have found multiple examples that show you how to add 2 decimal places to a double.However all the examples i found require you to change the double to a string format. such as

[c# double to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453951/c-sharp-double-tostring-formatting-with-two-decimal-places-but-no-rounding)

[formatting a double to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418668/formatting-a-double-to-two-decimal-places)

Is it possible to assign two decimal places and have it remain as a double?

for example double(25,2)

```
public double balance {get;set}

double money=145

balance=money
```

so the **balance** should now be **145.00**

**balance** should remain a double(25,2)

Comment: No. A double is defined as an 8-byte floating point number. It does not have a defined precision. See [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/215552) for much more information.

Comment: It's not hard to write a `struct` having two integer numbers for a whole part and a fractional part. If fractional part exceeds 100 you add `f / 100` to the whole part and you assign `f % 100` to the fractional part

Comment: Use `decimal` not `double`.

Answer (score 1):

No. The best way to handle that is *keep using a numeric type as long as possible*, and then only convert to string at the **last possible moment** before showing the value to a user.

Additionally, whenever you work with money you should prefer the `decimal` type over `double`. This still won't let you keep the two decimal places — *that's just not how numeric types work!* — but it will help you avoid rounding errors that can really matter when working with money.

Finally, if this is your property:

```
public decimal Balance {get;set;}
```

You can have an additional property that looks like this

```
public string BalanceString {get {return Balance.ToString("F2");} }
```

Note this property has no `set` and depends on the numeric `Balance` property.

Comment: I prefer this answer because you use `decimal` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. None of the .net data types are like this. Like oracle, where you can assign `number(10,2)`. In .net you need to separate operations from display. Whatever your value is, you can always format it for display like

```
double money = 145.2345d;
Console.WriteLine(money.ToString("#.00"));
```

Result: `145.23`
You can also use standard letter format options like `"C"`

```
Console.WriteLine(money.ToString("C"));
```

Result: `$145.23`

Comment: `Decimal` should always be used instead of `double` where money or currency is concerned.