# How to use String.Format specifier in an expression?

Tags: c#, string.format

```
double paintneeded = area/450;
```

When I run the above, I get the output as `0.444444444`, but I wanted only `0.44`.

I tried this, but it throws an error:

```
double paintneeded = String.Format("{0:0.00}", (area/450));

Console.WriteLine("Number of Gallons paint needed:\t{0}", paintneeded);
```

How do I use `String.Format` in this expression? Or can I use it in the `Console.WriteLine`? If so, how do I implement it?

Comment: String.Format returns a string, which you're trying to assign to a double.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using String Format to show decimal upto 2 places or simple integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)

Comment: You want result to be string or double?

Comment: Just to clarify: what do you want if the result is an exact value (no decimal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Number of Gallons paint needed:\t{0:F2}", area/450.0);
```

Comment: this was simple.. I made it so complicated           Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", (area /450)));

Answer (score 0):

First way, convert to string:

```
double area = 150;
string paintneeded = string.Format("{0:0.00}", (area/450d)).ToString();

Console.WriteLine("Number of Gallons paint needed:\t{0}", paintneeded);
```

Second way, convert to double:

```
double area = 150;
double paintneeded = area/450d;

Console.WriteLine("Number of Gallons paint needed:\t{0:0.00}", paintneeded);
```

Comment: Thanks Magistr_AVSH I was able to figure it out, but now iam struggling to include thousands separator and the digits after decimal together in one

Comment: salestax = Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0,0.00}",((subtotal * 8.25) / 100))); //o/p should be 1,749.00 but I got it as 1749   also if I want to have the o/p as 100.00 what needs to be changed in the syntax??

Comment: Why you convert string to double? Of course you are lose formatting. Do something like this   double area = 15000.179;
  Console.WriteLine(area.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); [netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fL1W4B)