# How to convert string to decimal with 3 decimal places?

Tags: c#, .net

```
string num = 23.6;
```

I want to know how can I convert it into decimal with 3 decimal places
like

```
decimal nn = 23.600
```

Is there any method?

Comment: May be the other way round?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer

Comment: use this String.Format("{0:0.000}", decimalvalue)

Comment: he want to convert string TO decimal not decimal TO string...

Comment: `23.6m == 23.600m`.  Just parse it using `decimal.Parse`.

Comment: Why do you need decimal with trailing zeroes ? If you want to print something, just format it using `string.Format` class or use any formatting overloads of  `.ToString()`

Comment: If you mean that you want to create a `Decimal` whith the trailing zeros you should use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor and speifiy the appropriate scaling factor.

Comment: @NirajDoshi: maybe he cannot change the code that displays the decimal but has to pass it as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try my best..

First of all your `string num = 23.6;` won't *even* compile. You need to use double quotes with your strings like `string num = "23.6";`

If you wanna get this as a `decimal`, you need to parse it first with a `IFormatProvider` that have `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(if your `CurrentCulture` uses `.` already, you *don't* have to pass second paramter);

```
decimal nn = decimal.Parse(num, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

<strike>Now we have a `23.6` as a `decimal` value. But as a value, `23.6`, `23.60`, `23.600` and `23.60000000000` are totally same, right? No matter which one you parse it to decimal, you will get the same value as a `23.6M` in debugger.</strike> Looks like these are *not* true. See Jon Skeet comments on this answer and his "Keeping zeroes" section on [Decimal floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) article.

Now what? Yes, we need to get it's *textual* representation as `23.600`. Since we need only decimal separator in a textual representation, [The `"F"` Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFormatString) will fits out needs.

```
string str = nn.ToString("F3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 23.600
```

Comment: (I know this is two years later...) "But as a value, 23.6, 23.60, 23.600 and 23.60000000000 are totally same, right?" No, they're not. `decimal` retains trailing zeroes. `Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse("1.0"))` and  `Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse("1.00"))` do different things.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm, if I understand correctly (which I don't think so but..), as a "value", they are same. `decimal.Parse("1.0") == decimal.Parse("1.000000")` returns `true` _no matter_ how many trailing zeros they have. But, what do you mean "do different things" in your sentence exactly? Is it the issue with "Keeping zeroes" on your [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx)?

Comment: @SonerGönül: For "do different things", did you try running the code? They print out "1.0" and "1.00" respectively. Yes, the `==` operator ignore the scale, but saying multiple values are "totally same" is incorrect - there is an easily-detectable difference between those values, in that you just have to convert them to strings. And yes, this is the first part of the "Keeping zeroes" section of that article.

Comment: And likewise "No matter which one you parse it to decimal, you will get the same value as a 23.6M in debugger" is incorrect - if you parse "23.6", you get 23.6m. If you parse "23.60" you get 23.60m etc. The debugger will show you the difference between those.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different concepts here.

1. Value
2. View

you can have a value of **1** and view it like **1.0** or **1.0000** or **+000001.00**.

you have string **23.6**. you can convert it to decimal using `var d = decimal.Parse("23.6")`

now you have a value equals to **23.6** you can view it like **23.600** by using `d.ToString("F3")`

you can [read more about formatting decimal values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But decimal stores the original number of decimal places which you can see if you use `nn.ToString()`. It does not show `23.6` but `23.600`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Decimal(v=vs.110).aspx): _"The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied."_

Answer (score 0):

the thing that works for me in my case is num.ToString("#######.###")

Answer (score -2):

A decimal is not a string, it does not display the trailing zeros. If you want a string that displays your 3 decimal places including trailing zeros, you can use string.Format:

```
decimal nn= 23.5;
var formattedNumber = string.Format("{0,000}", nn);
```

Comment: `decimal` *does* display trailing zeroes. For example: `Console.WriteLine(1.000m)` and `Console.WriteLine(1.0m)` print 1.000 and 1.0 respectively.