# convert string to decimal to string in c#

Tags: c#

```
String num = "93456"

decimal decinum = Convert.ToDecimal(num);
var newnum = decinum.ToString();
```

I need to convert string value into decimal value and back to string value

For instance, 93456 string format in to 93.456 decimal format then back to 93.456 string format.

I need to place a decimal after two fist digits of a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to decimal with 3 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754394/how-to-convert-string-to-decimal-with-3-decimal-places)

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt:

```
String myString = "93456";

if (myString.Length > 2)
{
    myString = myString.Insert(2, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
}

var myDecimal = decimal.Parse(myString);

Console.WriteLine(myDecimal);
Console.WriteLine(myDecimal.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal num = 93456;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(num.ToString());

if (sb.Length > 2)
    sb.Insert(2, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
                .NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);

Console.WriteLine(sb);

num = decimal.Parse(sb.ToString());

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

---

**Update**
we don't have alot of string manipulation,so don't need using StringBuilder.
also according the question we should use NumberDecimalSeparator
instead of CurrencyDecimalSeparator

```
decimal num = 93456;

string str = num.ToString();

if (str .Length > 2)
    str .Insert(2, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
                .NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

Console.WriteLine(str);

num = decimal.Parse(str);

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Comment: Why the StringBuilder? Also, why `CurrencyDecimalSeparator` and not `NumberDecimalSeparator`?

Comment: StringBuilder performance is better because string type is immutable,also we don't have alot of manipulation in string and not matter using string or StringBuilder.but using StringBuilder is a good habit.about NumberDecimalSeparator, you are right,it's better

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string num = TextBox1.Text; //"93456.12";
if (num.Length > 2)
{
    decimal decNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(num.Substring(0, 2) + "." + num.Substring(2, num.Length - 2).Replace(".",""));
     string strNumber = Convert.ToString(decNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
string num1 = "93456";
int value = Convert.ToInt32(num1);
int digits = (num1.Length - 2) > 0 ? (num1.Length - 2) : 0;
decimal number1 = value / Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, digits));
string result = number1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string num = "9312";
string newNum = num.Length > 2 ? num.Insert(2, ".") : num + ".000";
decimal newDecimal; 

if (Decimal.TryParse(newNum, out newDecimal))
    Console.WriteLine(newDecimal);
else
    Console.WriteLine("not a valid decimal '{0}'.", newDecimal);
```

Comment: This is missing the 2nd part of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
string num = "93456";

decimal decinum = decimal.Parse(num);

string newnum = decinum.ToString("#,#", new NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSeparator = "." });
```