# String format to add commas and only show two decimals if non zero

Tags: c#

So it is easy enough to optionally format to two decimal places if non-zero i.e:

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.451); // 123.45
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);
```

(Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21751068/2482265)

And it's easy enough to format with commas:

```
String.Format("{0:n}", 1234);
```

And with commas and no decimals:

```
String.Format("{0:n0}", 1234);
```

(Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/105793/2482265)

But how about with commas and 2 decimals if decimals are non zero, but otherwise no decimals

So

```
10000000 -> 10,000,000
10000000.234 -> 10,000,000.23
10000000.05 -> 10,000,000.05
```

Note that if the solution gives
    10000000.1 -> 10,000,000.1

That would be acceptable as although I want 2 decimal places, I am infact not dealing with money, so the 2nd decimal place being zero should mean it is not displayed.

Comment: dive into `NumberFormatInfo` class.

Comment: "##,#.##" should do the trick, see my ans below

Comment: see webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the format specifier:

```
"##,#0.##"
```

for example

```
string.Format("{0:##,#0.##}" ,number)
```

or

```
number.ToString("##,#0.##");
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yecJnT

Comment: Check the history. It was downvoted when it was wrong.

Comment: the main concern for @Knightsy was the decimal places, which was addressed first, then i added the group seperator after

Comment: This answer will display 0.234 as .23 - if you want to retain the front 0 use sgmoore's answer below or change `#.##` to `0.##`. This is the most complete answer with example so accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Try a format specifier of

```
"#,##0.##"
```

Comment: This also works on first glance, this answer displays 0.234 as 0.23 whereas @BhavO's answer displays .23 - My question was ambiguous for this scenario so this is a good answer as well as far as I can see