# Display decimal without trailing zeros in MVC view

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

How to display decimal with 3 zeros after comma, without trailing?
My code is

```
<td>@decimal.Parse(item.QuantityKg.ToString()).ToString("G29")</td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using String Format to show decimal upto 2 places or simple integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)

Comment: How about `ToString("N3")` instead?

Comment: What type is `QuantityKg`?

Comment: CodeCaster, format is decimal

Comment: @JurijusAmbros Then why you generate it's string representation and parse it to `decimal` if it is _already_ `decimal`? Why not just `<td>@item.QuantityKg.ToString("N3")</td>` instead?

Comment: I can't give argument for ToString() method

Comment: @JurijusAmbros Why? You _already_ give an argument in your code example as `ToString("G29")`.

Comment: it gave me an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @JurijusAmbros Than I _strongly_ suspect your `item.QuantityKg` does not return `decimal` because `N` specifier works for `decimal` type.

Comment: in Model: `public decimal? QuantityKg { get; set; }`

Comment: `String.Format("{0:N3}",item.QuantityKg)` will work with both `decimal` and `decimal?`. As a rule, `String.Format` works even if a type's specific `ToString()` doesn't allow a formatting string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `QuantityKg` is `decimal?` instead of `decimal`, you can use it's [`Value` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use [`"N"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) with `3` precision.

If everything is *okey* other than this, this should work in your case;

```
<td>@item.QuantityKg.Value.ToString("N3")</td>
```

But this throws `InvalidOperationException` if `QuantityKg` is `null`, so using `string.Format` would be better to catch this situation which generates empty string if it is `null` as Panagiotis [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317745/display-decimal-without-trailing-zeros-in-mvc-view/35318308#comment58345446_35317745).

```
<td>@string.Format("{0:N3}", item.QuantityKg)</td>
```

Comment: Or use String.Format, so that a null value will result in an empty string instead of an YSOD. It also doesn't care if the value is `decimal` or `decimal?`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, that's seems better. Added my answer. Thanks.