# how to convert decimal value into int in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have decimal values in the database. I want to show the decimal value in it. How to convert decimal values into it.

```
int vatprice;
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
vatprice = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][5].ToString());//getting error here
```

Comment: What is the error message? What is the value of `dt.Rows[0][5].ToString()` exactly? Why do you get it as an int if it is decimal?

Comment: Hey, Please ask question here with more clarification. What exception you are getting and also what is value of  dt.Rows[0][5] .

Comment: vatprice = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0][5].ToString());// how to restrict decimal upto max of two decimal after decimal

Comment: You declare `vatprice` as `int` and now you want to assign a `decimal` value to it with a maximum of 2 positions after the decimal point?

Comment: i used this ,  totalPriceWithVAT = Math.Round(totalPriceWithVAT, 2);, but getting oonly 1 decimal value

Comment: then for rounding you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer

Comment: thanks u guys i got my answer. i changed into to decimal and used -  vatprice = Math.Round(vatprice, 2);

Comment: that's probably because the decimal part ends with a 0, use string.format() as suggested by @Claudius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, round decimal up to 2 place using following way :

1) Use `Math.Round()`.

```
 var vatprice= Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(dt.Rows[0][5], 2));
```

2) second way is

```
var vatprice=Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0][5].ToString ("#.##"));
```