# Display two decimal places for a string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, decimal

I've retrieved a decimal value from database as a string:

```
string get_amt = dt_.Rows[i]["billing_amt"].ToString();
```

Values of `billing_amt` are `100.0000`, `150.0000`, `0.0000`.

I tried to display the value of `get_amt` rounding up to two decimal places using the code:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", get_amt)
```

but it is not working. How can I show the value of `get_amt` as `100.00` or `150.00`? Please suggest.

Comment: I suggest you actually **convert the values to decimal** and then you can display them any way you want. ... you should *always* use the appropriate data type - and for a decimal, that's **not** a string .....

Comment: Is not there any other way?

Comment: `double x = 100.0000;
  Console.Write(x.ToString("N2"));`

Comment: Check out this old answer from SO, maybe it will help you: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to try something like:

```
double get_amt = 0;

if (dt_.Rows[i]["billing_amt"] != DBNull.Value)
    get_amt = Convert.ToDouble(dt_.Rows[i]["billing_amt"]);
```

Then:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", get_amt)
```

should work.

It's currently not working as it's a string value your trying to format - which wont have decimal places.

Comment: You should **avoid** using the `double` or `float` types - use `decimal` to avoid rounding errors!

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you could use Regex to cut the string down to a 2 decimal point number like so:

```
string formatted = Regex.Match(unformattedString, @"^-?\d+\.\d{2}").Value;
```

That being said, you almost never want to use a string to hold number information. It's a bother and a pain to get them to do what you want. It's much more advisable to store them as either a `double` or a `decimal`, then convert to string only when you have to.

Comment: Avoid `double` (or `float`) - use `decimal` to avoid rounding errors

Comment: @marc_s Unless you need a high level of precision, `double` isn't likely to cause any rounding issues significant enough to really do much. And if OP only needs the values to the second decimal point, I'd say that `double` is fine.