# C# how to parse a string to double

Tags: c#, parsing

I want to parse my string to double. My problem is that the result of newTime is 800, but the result should be 8,00.

```
string time = "08:00";
double newTime = double.Parse(time.Replace(':', '.'));
```

Comment: `8,00` isn't a valid double

Comment: I get `8` when I execute your code

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Calculate number of hours from HH:mm format?

Comment: Times aren't doubles. It's very unclear what you're asking here...

Comment: But I want to get 8,00 with two decimalpoints

Comment: I suppose your culture has , as decimal separator. So try to parse like thi: double newTime = double.Parse(time.Replace(':', '.'),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: I think that the problem is with styling output. You should use string formatting like **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-upto-2-places-or-simple-integer)**

Comment: I have try to parse with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, but it brings nothing, the result is still 8.

Comment: @A.H yes that is correct it cannot be nothing else as you have double not string. What would you like to get string without leading zero and , insetead of : ?

Comment: @A.H Just listen to all these people instead of saying err derr result is still 8. Its a double 8,0 = 8 period. Would you write "Do that 5 times" -> "Do that 5,0 times"... No you don't. The way you wan't to format you just need a string, Piotr Kamoda has the perfect answer for that in his comment

Comment: Thanks @Piotr Kamoda

Comment: If it is a time, why don't you just parse into a TimeSpan object? ie TimeSpan.Parse("08:00")

Comment: @A.H ok now i understand what you want, so it is probably the best to do it like this time.Replace(':', ',').TrimStart('0')

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat `:` as a *decimal separator*, just *do it*:

```
  string time = "08:00";

  // when parsing "time", decimal separator is ":"
  double newTime = double.Parse(time, 
    new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = ":" });
```

Try avoiding tricks with magic constants like `'.'` in the `time.Replace(':', '.')`. Please, notice that `newTime` will be `8`, not `8.00` (since `8 == 8.0 == 8.00 == 8.000...`). If you want to *represent* `newTime` with *two* digits after the decimal point use *formatting*:

```
  // F2 - format string ensures 2 digits after the decimal point
  // Outcome: 8.00
  Console.Write(newTime.ToString("F2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `Double.Parse` is a `Double`, not a string. You need to output a string from the double, using `ToString`.

You should also use an overload of `Double.Parse` that has a `NumberStyles`  parameter. Using the `Float` value allows exponent notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
string time = "08:00";
double newTime = double.Parse(time.Replace(':', '.'),  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your culture has a different decimal separator to what you are creating in your string.

You can change it to to this

```
string time = "08:00";
double newTime = double.Parse(time.Replace(":", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator) );
```

Comment: newTime is still 8. but i want 8,00

Comment: @A.H then you want a string. A double will only show decimals if there are any