# Getting incorrect decimal places with percentage calculation

Tags: c#

I am performing calculations on 2 numbers like below :

```
No1 = 263
No2 = 260
Decimal places = 2
Expected output = 98.86
```

**Code :**

```
decimal output = 0;
 int decimalPlaces = 2;
 if (No1 > 0)
        output = ((100 * Convert.ToDecimal(((No2 * 100) / No1))) / 100);
 output = TruncateDecimal(output, decimalPlaces); // 98

    public static decimal TruncateDecimal(decimal value, int precision)
    {
        decimal step = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);
        decimal tmp = Math.Truncate(step * value);
        return tmp / step;
    }
```

Above code renders output = 98

When i divide 263/260 in calculator i get 0.988593

**decimalPlaces = 2 :** Take 2 digits after decimal places

**decimalPlaces = 2 :** Round off will also take from this position after 2 decimal places i.e round off should take from 593 rendering 98.86

```
No1 = 117
No2 = 120
decimal places = 2
Expected Output = 97.50
```

Can anybody please me with this?

Comment: Integer division at work here. Change your constants to be 100m (notice the m suffix)

Comment: Also, do no reinvent the wheel. _Math.Round(output, 2);_ and remove your _TruncateDecimal_

Comment: @Steve Now i am getting 98.85 instead of 98.86

Comment: Exactly, because you have reinvented the wheel but not have made it perfectly round.

Comment: @SteveWhy do i need to put m as suffix with 100?Sorry if this sounds as silly question

Comment: Without _m_ the constants are considered to be integers. So the operator choosen to divide your numbers is the integer divisor. Which doesn't account for decimals and your op returns 98. With the m suffix the constant are decimals and the operator choosen is the decimal divisor.

Comment: [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/division-operator) _When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer_

Answer (score 1):

The problem is integer division.  When you divide an integer by an integer, you will get an integer.  You need to cast the values (at minimum one of them) to a decimal

```
output = Math.Round((100 * ((decimal)No2/(decimal)No1)),2);
```

Comment: When i take No2=2 and No1=5 then i get 40.0 instead of 40.00 for decimalPlaces=2

Comment: And what is mathematically the difference between 40 and 40.00 ? Do not confuse the decimal value with how that value is presented on video or paper.

Comment: I know there is no difference but i have to show it like that

Comment: If your problem is display purposes, look into string.Format().   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951335/using-string-format-to-show-decimal-up-to-2-places-or-simple-integer

Answer (score 0):

try to change some parenthesis positions, from:

```
output = ((100 * Convert.ToDecimal(((No2 * 100) / No1))) / 100);
```

to

```
output = ((100 * ((Convert.ToDecimal(No2 * 100) / No1))) / 100);
```

In your code the division is calculated **before** decimal conversion, so you convert only integer result of the division.

Besides use Math.Round instead of Math.Truncate, in order to get your desired result.